# Captcha substitution on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, security, captcha, hmac

We have a service where user can sign-up. This process is protected by reCAPTCHA to prevent automatized sign-ups. The problem is that on mobile devices reCAPTCHA is not a convenience. Therefore we decided that the sign-up API will accept also some special *tokens* instead of reCAPTCHA response.

Now the question is how to implement this *token*. Our first approach was to equip the mobile application with some constant secret that would be sent to the server as the *token*. But this secret can be revealed if a hacker redirects the request to his server (by updating DNS record of the API domain and installing his certificate as trusted to the mobile device).

Now our final approach is to compute the token as HMAC-SHA1 on username+secret (do we need a here secred - maybe just for making the input long enough?). The username will be taken from sign-up input. Then the server would authorize it by validating the hash. In his case it would be possible to do a replay attack but it is OK because duplicate username would be rejected.

Is this approach correct? Maybe there are other alternatives to captcha on mobile devices?

Also is it possible to get and reverse engineer the application from iOS (ipa file) considering it will be hosted in Appstore and to extract the key (and secret)?

In case of android this is possible - is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with [Hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) to not to send credentials over the wire. It will be used for iOS where it shouldn't be possible to reverse engineer the app and get the secret key. For Android we'll use some reCAPTCHA library for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You found the disadvantage: you still with a token which doesn't change for the same user. It's ok in your use case (register), but there could be another use cases where is not useful (for example a password recovery feature. In that case, a possible hacker might generate valid tokens for any user is your are asking for the username).

My solution would be:

- Create an algorithm (on both mobile app and your backend) that takes a "public token" and creates a "secret token", which solves the captcha. It might be a simple SHA1 hash (I don't recommend), a combination between public token and a salt, the user id and public token, etc...
- Create an endpoint on your API that generates public and secret tokens. Store secret token in your backend and return public token to the client (mobile app).
- You app then should ask for the public token, generate the secret token and send it to the API. The API verifies that secret token is already stored in your database, and if it's the case then captcha is solved.

An improvement would be making stored secret tokens to expire after X seconds.

Hope it helps!